# What is the best way to solve for this recursion?

Tags: c#, recursion, time-complexity

I'm studying on my own and came across the following problem, and I don't know much C# (I'm coming from JavaScript). See below for my guess and any extra explanation/clarification/correction is welcome.

What does the following code do and how would you improve the code (Given n=1 and m=10)?

```
class Program
{  public static int DoSomething(int n, int m)
   {
      int x = n;

      if (n < m)
      {
        n++;
        return x += DoSomething(n, m);
      }
      return x;
   }

   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
     Console.WriteLine("Enter n: ");
     int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

     Console.WriteLine("Enter m: ");
     int m = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

     int x = DoSomething(n, m) ;

     Console.WriteLine(x);

     Console.ReadKey();
   }
}
```

So it's obviously a recursion problem right? It looks like it will increment n until it is greater than m and then write that number to the console. So eventually it will log 11 to the console (I'm assuming in total, it will log 1-11 to the console). The recursion is redundant and unnecessary and so the easy solution to me would be to just convert it to a simple while loop, where as long as n < m, Console.WriteLine(n) and n++. Am I missing something, or is that the best simple solution in this scenario?

Comment: hi cody g. welcome to stackoverflow. there is a glaring issue in your question, if `n >= m`, the `DoSomething` can't return - hence it wont compile as pointed by diplomacynotwar.

Comment: Good catch, I missed the return for x, edited it back in. Does that help?

Comment: So upon looking at it further, it returns the sums of the iterations. When m=10, x=55 or 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10. So, my next question is what is the best way to write that without recursion?

Comment: If you can't work out the exact formula for how the recursive solution behaves, at the very least you could convert it to a loop. However, the sum of 1..N is a solved problem, and is equal to N*(N+1)/2. Sum of N..M is equal to SUM(1..M) - SUM(1..N-1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the following formula ([source](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1842203)), you can rewrite your code as a calculation:

[image]

Note: α represents `n` and β represents `m`.

Which can be expressed in code as:

```cs
public static int DoSomething(int n, int m)
{
    int numerator = (m - n + 1) * (n + m);
    int result = numerator / 2;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That definitely seems like the simplest solution, instead of a loop or something else to simplify the actual process.

Comment: FYI Some compilers will perform optimisations like this for you, at least for some cases, under the name of "scalar evolution".